# Why does my lat /lng shows null or undefined?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to making IP Address Tracker using Next JS. I want the coordinates of the map to change every time the user click the button.

My `Map.js` file:

```
const Maps = ({ results }) => {
console.log(results);
const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState({ lat: null, lng: null });
let lat = results.latitude;
let lng = results.longitude;
useEffect(() => {
setGeoData({ lat: lat, lng: lng });
 }, []);
 console.log(geoData);
 return (
 <MapContainer
  center={[59.2322, -12.42221]}
  zoom={14}
  scrollWheelZoom={false}
  style={{
    height: "800px",
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: "1",
    }}
     >
   <TileLayer
     attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
     url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  />
  {geoData.lat && geoData.lng && (
    <Marker position={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]} />
  )}
</MapContainer>
   );  
 };
```

I am passing the `results` from a different file.

```
const MapsNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("./MapsNoSSR.js"), { ssr: false 
});
 import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
  const Header () => {
   ....
  return 
<MapsNoSSR results={results} />
     }
```

Comment: What is the `results` object - where is it coming from - have you verified it returns `results.latitude` ?

Comment: Yess I did...It comes from a different file

Comment: could you post the response of the results

Comment: Its an object:
city: "Frankfurt am Main"
completed_requests: 2
continent: "Europe"
continent_code: "EU"
country: "Germany"
country_capital: "Berlin"
country_code: "DE"
country_flag: "https://cdn.ipwhois.io/flags/de.svg"
country_neighbours: "CH,PL,NL,DK,BE,CZ,LU,FR,AT"
country_phone: "+49"
currency: "Euro"
ip: "18.184.214.33"
isp: "Amazon.com, Inc."
latitude: 50.1107715
longitude: 8.6822223
region: "Hessen"
timezone_gmt: "GMT +1:00"

Comment: And how are you passing it to `Maps` - post the code that invokes the code to `Map.js`

Comment: const MapsNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("./MapsNoSSR.js"), { ssr: false });
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";  <div id="map">
        <MapsNoSSR results={results} />
      </div>

Comment: See here - looks like someone had a similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65563974/13749957

Comment: I think its a different one but we will see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want your `useEffect` hook to be called again whenever `results` changes, so put `results` in its dependency array. An empty dependency array means React is going to run the effect only once

```
const Maps = ({ results }) => {
  const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState({ lat: null, lng: null });
  useEffect(() => {
    setGeoData({ lat: results.lattitude, lng: results.longtitude });
  }, [results]);
  return ...;
};
```

Also, make sure you are using the correct component. Seems like you have the `Maps` component then also the `MapsNoSSR` component